# Three two digit numbers are such that the sum of any two is formed of the same digits as the third number but in reverse order.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Three two-digit numbers are such that the sum of any two is formed of the same digits as the third number but in reverse order. Find the sum of all three numbers.

Let the numbers be $\overline {ab}$, $\overline {cd}$, $\overline{ef}$.

We get the equations $$\begin{align} 
10(a+c)+b+d=10f+e\\
10(a+e)+b+f=10d+c\\
10(c+e)+d+f=10b+a\end{align}$$
How to solve further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Adding the three equations together and collecting terms, we get $$19(a+c+e)=8(b+d+f)$$

Since $8(b+d+f)$ is a multiple of $19$ and $b+d+f$ is the sum of three digits, what can you conclude from there?

> It must be that $b+d+f=19$, from which we get $a+c+e=8$.  In any solution to this problem, the sum of the three numbers would have to be $10\cdot8=19=99$.

Comment: FWIW, there are 5 solutions, or 2 if we don't allow repetitions. (Assuming I haven't made some stupid blunder).

Comment: @PM2Ring Nice!  I came up with 36, 27, 36 before deciding that I didn't care enough to see if there were solutions without repetitions.  ^_^

Comment: The two solutions without repetitions are $18,27,54$ and $18,36,45$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I'm not surprised.  My "multiples of 9" sense went off when I read the problem statement.

Comment: The possible solutions $(a,c,e)$ are the 5 partitions of 8 of size 3, and the corresponding $(b,d,f)$ are the 5 partitions of 19 of size 3 with maximum element 8. And of course $a+b=c+d=e+f=9$.